# Wordpress Registration Plugin with payment option

Tags: wordpress

May I need a help member registration plugin with payment option with 2 or 3 types for user, Please tell me a good plugin for registration payment plugin. Thank you so much.

Comment: stackoverflow is a place to share/request coding support. But not for this kind of support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/

You may find it useful for your requirement